# Put ng-class attribute to angular-formly field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

Hi everyone I’m trying to create a form with angular-formly I have this definition:

```
{
        "options": {
            "data": {
                "someData": 6
            }
        },
        "fieldGroup": [
            {
                "className": "ctnStepper",
                "key": "customField ",
                "type": "form-section"
            },
            {
                "className": "ctnChamp",
                "key": "inputTest",
                "type": "input"
            }
        ]
}
```

And I want to put ng-class attribute on the inputTest field so after, the generated form would yield something like this:

```
<input ng-class="{ 'myClass': model. Something != somethingElse }">
```

I tried to do this tanks to the ngModelElAttrs but it’s hard to understand and I’m stuck here. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Augustin

Comment: use this way

<input ng-class="{ 'myClass': model.Something !== somethingElse }">

Comment: Remove the space between `model.` and `Something`

Answer (score 1):

I've assgned class to div, you can use as per your requirement.

```
ng-class="{'alert-danger':x.key=='customField', 'alert-info':x.key=='inputTest'}"
```

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  
  
    $scope.myData={
        "options": {
            "data": {
                "someData": 6
            }
        },
        "fieldGroup": [
            {
                "className": "ctnStepper",
                "key": "customField",
                "type": "form-section"
            },
            {
                "className": "ctnChamp",
                "key": "inputTest",
                "type": "input"
            }
        ]
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in myData.fieldGroup">
      <div class="alert" ng-class="{'alert-danger':x.key=='customField', 'alert-info':x.key=='inputTest'}">{{x.className}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```